# "Luck", "coincidence", "chance" — most appropriate in this situation?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, nouns

> I found my present flat completely by **__**.
>
> 1. luck
> 2. coincidence
> 3. chance

What will be the most appropriate word in this sentence?

Comment: You could also say "I found my present flat serendipitously." This would be especially appropriate if you weren't actively looking for it at that time. http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/serendipitously

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[By chance](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/by_chance) is what you are looking for, as you found it unexpectedly. Also it sounds the most natural.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, any of the words would work just about as well in your example: *by chance* and *by coincidence* emphasize the random nature of the occurrence and are interchangeable, while *by luck* adds an element of good fortune to it. The concept of luck mitigates the sense of randomness to some extent, as many people perceive luck to be a mystical, deterministic power that operates on behalf of someone.

So it all depends on what you mean.

Comment: By chance IS luck - by luck sounds wrong

Comment: I agree with mplungjan. "I found my ___ by luck" is non-idiomatic. I can't imagine a native speaker saying that under any circumstances. "I found my ___ by coincidence" is quasi-possible as an introductory clause, in the event that something else happened of significance. "By chance" means "by accident" in this context and is natural.

Comment: @mplungjan, @The Raven: Well, in the sense that you can have good luck or bad luck, sure. But I believe I qualified the statement sufficiently. For some people, *luck* is deterministic, not random, and that's what they mean when they use the word. And if you can say you found something "by sheer good luck" you ought to be able to say you found it "by luck" — or so it seems to me.

Comment: @The Raven I'm with @Robusto on this. I don't think *by luck* is non-idiomatic. A simple google search for "by luck" returns many results. In fact, the phrase would sound far more natural to me than *by chance* in several situations: "Did you win that game of darts by luck or by skill?"

Comment: @The Raven Of course, now that I posted that I realize you mean "I found my X by luck" is non-idiomatic, not just "by luck." Even then, I respectfully disagree. I would use "by chance" if I wasn't actively looking for/missing something, but If I were looking for something and somehow stumbled upon it in an unlikely location, I could imagine exclaiming "I found my missing X purely by luck!"

Answer (score 0):

Chance is best.  Happenstance is another way of saying coincidence.

Comment: Hello, Ron Royston. _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) defines _happenstance_ as "a circumstance esp. that is due to chance," so you would strengthen your answer if you could point to a reference work that supports your view that _happenstance_ is closer in meaning to "coincidence." It's an interesting idea in any case.